# Help fix a small htaccess issue reguarding mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[a-z]+.orbno.com$
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?orbno.com$
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} download/
>   RewriteRule (.*) /download.php\?action=$1&user=%1 [L]

Two small issues, this is the output:

array(2) { ["action"]=>  string(23) "download/email-logo.png" ["user"]=>  string(0) "" }

1. I want the user to be the subdomain they are accessing, i have wild-card DNS, how do i pass that, since %1 isnt working.
2. Is there a way to only pass email-logo.png instead of download/email-logo.png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lump in #apache on freenode helped me out.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]+).orbno.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?orbno.com$
RewriteRule download/(.+) download.php?action=$1&user=%1

Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try $1 instead of %1

Comment: That cant work becuase $1 is already giving me an output, take a look at the example output.